# listItems.forEach is not a function

Tags: javascript, react-native

I have a problem with this code:

```
const [listItems, setListItems] = useState(TEMP_DATA_CART)
  const handleRemove = (id) => {
    const newList = listItems.filter((item) => item.id !== id)
    setListItems(newList)
}
const [checked, setChecked] = useState(false)
  let totalPrice = 0
  listItems.forEach((item) => {
    totalPrice += item.value * item.quantity
  })
  const onSubtract = (item, index) => {
    const list = [...listItems]
    listItems[index].quantity -= 1
    setListItems({ list })
  }
  const onAdd = (item, index) => {
    const list = [...listItems]
    listItems[index].quantity += 1
    setListItems({ list })
  }
```

When I click on plus or minus button => error

[image: when i click]
[image: my error]

Comment: That error means that `listItems` isn't an array. Make sure it's an array.

Comment: What is ```TEMP_DATA_CART```? Can you log it?

Comment: Is your ```listItems``` an object? You cant use ```.forEach``` method on objects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cant use `.forEach` method on objects.

Change this:

```
const onSubtract = (item, index) => {
   const list = [...listItems]
   listItems[index].quantity -= 1
   setListItems({ list })
}
const onAdd = (item, index) => {
  const list = [...listItems]
   listItems[index].quantity += 1
   setListItems({ list })
}
```

to this:

```
const onSubtract = (item, index) => {
   const list = [...listItems]
   listItems[index].quantity -= 1
   setListItems(list)
}
const onAdd = (item, index) => {
  const list = [...listItems]
   listItems[index].quantity += 1
   setListItems(list)
}
```

Comment: tks, u help me a lot